# BottomSheetBehaviour setstate without animation

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet

I have tried the new `BottomSheetBehaviour` with design library **23.0.2** but i think it too limited. When I change state with `setState()` method, the bottomsheet use ad animation to move to the new state.

How can I change state immediately, without animation? I don't see a public method to do that.

Comment: Corresponding issue on Android issuetracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62124243

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately it looks like you can't. Invocation of `BottomSheetBehavior`'s `setState` ends with synchronous or asynchronous call of `startSettlingAnimation(child, state)`. And there is no way to override these methods behavior cause `setState` is final and `startSettlingAnimation` has package visible modifier. Check the sources for more information.

I have problems with the same, but in a bit different way - my UI state changes `setHideable` to false before that settling animation invokes, so I'm getting `IllegalStateException` there. I will consider usage of `BottomSheetCallback` to manage this properly.

Comment: When I call setState() to expanded, I get the animation, but I do not get it for STATE_COLLAPSED. It's very confusing to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the show/close animation you can use `dialog.window?.setWindowAnimations(-1)`. For instance:

```
class MyDialog(): BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)

        dialog.window?.setDimAmount(0f) // for removing the dimm
        dialog.window?.setWindowAnimations(-1) // for removing the animation

        return dialog
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need it, then you can resort to reflection:

```
  fun BottomSheetBehavior.getViewDragHelper(): ViewDragHelper? = BottomSheetBehavior::class.java
    .getDeclaredField("viewDragHelper")
    .apply { isAccessible = true }
    .let { field -> field.get(this) as? ViewDragHelper? }

  fun ViewDragHelper.getScroller(): OverScroller? = ViewDragHelper::class.java
    .getDeclaredField("mScroller")
    .apply { isAccessible = true }
    .let { field -> field.get(this) as? OverScroller? }
```

Then you can use these extension methods when the state changes:

```
  bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetCallback() {
      override fun onSlide(view: View, offset: Float) {}

      override fun onStateChanged(view: View, state: Int) {
        if (state == STATE_SETTLING) {
           try { 
              bottomSheetBehavior.getViewDragHelper()?.getScroller()?.abortAnimation()
           } catch(e: Throwable) {}
        }
      }
    })
```

I will add that the code is not perfect, getting fields every time the state changes is not efficient, and this is done for the sake of simplicity.